# Does "almost the first ten" mean "almost first" or "almost ten"?

Tags: grammar, ambiguity, attachment-ambiguity

If someone is talking "almost the first ten minutes" of something, should that be interpreted as being:

- ten minutes, almost at the beginning, or
- almost ten minutes, necessarily starting at the beginning?

Comment: Needs some context but I'm assume the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret it as the latter, starting at the beginning and talking for almost 10 minutes.